# Can solver work if recorded for a macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I've recorded a Macro in Excel, and assigned that macro to a button. When I press the button, I want to automatically perform the optimisation (solver) to find the optimum solution.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Macro15()
    SolverOk SetCell:="$B$37", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$B$8", Engine:= _
        1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
End Sub
```

However, it only works when I do it manually. When I press the button which I assigned the macro to, it does not work and there is no solution. It remains as before. Is there a way to record it or do I have to do it manually, such as set the constraints right in the VBA console.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/using-the-solver-vba-functions)? And in particular, establishing a reference to the Solver add-in.

Comment: Try calling `SolverReset` first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Solver Error while using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418409/excel-solver-error-while-using-vba)